# Use .gitignore on a per remote basis?

Tags: git

Is it possible to .gitignore on a per-remote basis? I want to be able to pull core updates from an open source project's public repo but push local changes from a (currently) .gitignored directory to my private git repo on a different remote. Is this possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** On further reflection, it looks like git submodules might be a good way to handle this.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

**EDIT2:** I've been using submodules all day and that solution appears perfect for what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `.gitignore` file is stored in the repository, it is versioned like 
any other file. As such it can differ by branch, so you can make any changes to 
your local copy that you like and commit those to your local branch(es).

The contents of the `.gitignore` file do not affect retrieving contents of a 
repository, so having local changes will not change the results that you get 
when you pull from the projects public repo. But, you may need to manually 
resolve conflicts in that file when the version from the public repository 
changes.

Alternatively, you could just leave the `.gitignore` file alone and use `git 
add -f` to add the files that you want to track locally. Once a file has been 
added to the git repository it being ignored will have no effect. But if you 
are regularly adding files to the ignored directory it would likely be a good 
idea to modify the `.gitignore` file so that git can remind you that there are 
files which need to be added.

If you are going to be making other changes which you would like to send 
upstream to the public project, those should be made on a branch without your 
local changes to the `.gitignore` file and the additions of those otherwise 
ignored files. You can then merge those changes into your local branch with the 
ignored files for your normal use.

Comment: Interesting. So I'd create and switch to a branch then remove the directory I want to track from .gitignore. Then I can track it and push to my private repo. Then switch back to the project's branch when I need to pull project updates to the core app?

Comment: If those are the only changes that you're planning to make you wouldn't need to do any branch switching. You're already on a private branch by the nature of git as a distributed system, and pulling in changes from an upstream repository is exactly what `git pull` is designed to do.

Comment: Brilliant. I pulled from origin master and that merged upstream project commits into my local dev branch. (Core development and local development files are in different directories, so there shouldn't be a conflict.) Then I pushed that branch to my private repo, which now contains everything. Sound right?

Comment: Yes. Although if you modify the `.gitignore` file there could always be a conflict with that. But I'd expect that to be rare, and fairly easy to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem where I worked with 2 remotes and needed to ignore different files over them.

This is what i did:

```
 $ git fetch <public remote>
```

Merge all but exclude changes to the current *.gitignore*

```
 $ git merge --no-ff --no-commit <public remote>/master
 $ git checkout master path/to/.gitignore
 $ git commit -m "Merged ... into ... excluding the .gitignore"
```

This way I pull the changes from a remote and keep my existing *.gitignore* file

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so -- but git has surprised me before.

It is my understanding that `.gitignore` is repository scoped and applies to everything.

It is possible to explicitly `git add ...` specific ignored files, which git will then continue tracking as if they were not ignored -- but that is not per remote.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You'll need to maintain separate branches for that.